# Prevent Multiple Months datepicker showing the next month after select date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I created a form with jquery datepicker to be able to select date, this datepicker will have 2 months displayed.

```
$("#date-input").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

[image]

by default it will show the current month and the next month. The problem is when i choose the month on the right side which is the greater month, when the datepicker shows up again it will make the previous month dissapear and replaced with the selected month , and the right side will be filled with the next month of selected month. How can i keep the month on the left stay when i choose a date on the right side month?

when i choose 10 March 2020, by default when i click the datepicker again
[image]

what i want when i click the datepicker again:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can change that UI behaviour (although I'm happy to be proved wrong). I think all you can do is use the `maxDate` and `minDate` properties to restrict the dates which can be selected